# Three.js meshGroup once moved can't move back

Tags: three.js, gsap

I am trying to move a meshGroup to the right, and then move it back. But once the meshGroup is moved it can not move again, like only move to the right or left it works fine, but once it is moved it won't move back to the left or right. I am using meshGroup.position.x to do the movement, here is the code:

```js
const moveMeshRight = (mainMeshGroup:Group) => {
            gsap.to(mainMeshGroup.position, {
                duration: 0.5,
                x: 115,
                onUpdate:()=>{
                    console.log(mainMeshGroup.position)
                }
            })
            gsap.to(mainCamera.position,{
                duration:0.5,
                z:500
            })
        }

        const moveMeshLeft = (mainMeshGroup:Group) => {
            gsap.to(mainMeshGroup.position, {
                duration: 0.5,
                x:-115,
                onUpdate:()=>{
                console.log(mainMeshGroup.position)
            }
            })
        }
```

They are used in two click event:

```html
<div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
        {drawer?null:display1Fade}

        {drawer?null:<Button style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            height: '60px',
            marginLeft: '16px',
            marginTop: '16px',
            zIndex: 1
        }} onClick={() => {
            setDrawer(true);
            //mainMeshGroup.position.x+=50
            moveMeshRight(mainMeshGroup)
        }}>

        </Button>}
      <div className={drawer?classes.displayButtonDivMove:classes.displayButtonDiv}>
          {<div className={detail?classes.displayButtonExpand1:classes.displayButton}
                onClick={()=>{
                    setDisplay1(true);
                    setDrawer(false);
                    moveMeshLeft(mainMeshGroup)
                }}>
              Display Type 1</div>}
          {<div style={{marginLeft: '10px'}} className={detail?classes.displayButtonExpand2:classes.displayButton} onClick={()=>{setDisplay1(false);setDrawer(false)}}>Display Type 2</div>}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example that demonstrate simple left/right animations controlled via two buttons:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

let group;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 4;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  group = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add(group);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  group.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const btnLeft = document.getElementById('btn-left');
  btnLeft.addEventListener('pointerdown', moveLeft);

  const btnRight = document.getElementById('btn-right');
  btnRight.addEventListener('pointerdown', moveRight);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function moveLeft() {

  gsap.to(group.position, {
    duration: 1,
    x: -1
  });

}

function moveRight() {

  gsap.to(group.position, {
    duration: 1,
    x: 1
  });

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.130.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btn-left">
    Left
  </button>
  <button id="btn-right">
    Right
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. When I enter the page, if the first thing I do is to trigger the move mesh group event, it can move once but after that, it won't move again; if I don't trigger the move event first, like click other button or open up a drawer first then try to trigger the move event, it will not move at all, not even once. Do you know why?

Comment: Please create a live example that shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: My project is created with React, TypeScript, and Three.js, I am not sure how to create an example in jsfiddle that can show the same issue, but thank you anyway.